# Add a node to TTreeView in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, treeview, c++builder

It is a very simple question that I have to ask, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I'm using C++ Builder XE6 and I want to use a TTreeView. I have found several tutorials about it, saying that the method to add a node is to do this :

```
TreeView->Items->Add(NULL, "name");
```

But it doesn't work, I get the error that Add() is not a member of Items. After a quick research, I have found that Add() is a method for TTreeNodes, but TreeView->Items is a TTreeViewItem. Maybe all the tutorials that I have read are outdated. Anyway, I can't find any way to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TTreeViewItem` is a FireMonkey class, not a VCL class.  All of the tutorials you have read are likely based on VCL.

In VCL, `TTreeView::Items` as a `TTreeNodes` object:

```
__property TTreeNodes* Items = {read=FTreeNodes, write=SetTreeNodes};
```

`TTreeNodes` does have an `Add()` method:

```
TTreeNode* __fastcall Add(TTreeNode* Sibling, const System::String S);
```

The code you showed works fine in VCL.

In FireMonkey, `TTreeView::Items` is an indexed array of `TTreeViewItem` objects:

```
__property TTreeViewItem* Items[int Index] = {read=GetTreeItem};
```

`TTreeViewItem` does not have an `Add()` method.  The correct way to add a new node to a FireMonkey `TTreeView` is to create a `TTreeViewItem` object and set its `Parent` property, eg:

```
TTreeViewItem *node = new TTreeViewItem(TreeView);
node->Text = "name";
node->Parent = TreeView;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I thought it was VCL components in FireMonkey too. It's more clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `TreeView->Items->AddChild(NULL, "name");` - This will add a child node of root (NULL). If you need to add a child of a specific node then you need to pass the node as parameter.

According to the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView), and a quick check in the hpp file, `Items` is a `TTreeNodes` so `Add` and `AddChild` should work. Are you sure you're not accessing, for instance, `Items[0]` ?

Comment: What you say is true for VCL, but not for FireMonkey. The compiler says `Items` is a `TTreeViewItem` object, which is only true in FireMonkey.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, I don't use FireMonkey so I didn't know that. The OP didn't specify which technology was in use.

Comment: My bad, I'm a little confused between VCL and FireMonkey, I actually thought it was VCL components in FireMonkey too. Thank you for your help though.